# regex get repeating group matches individually

Tags: php, regex

I have this regular expression.

```
/(#LOG(\(.*?\))+\s+)(((ENTRY\([a-z]+\)+(\{[a-z]\})?))(.*?)(?=ENTRY|#END))+(\s*#END)/is
```

And the following text.

```
#LOG(pid1234)(20052013)

  ENTRY(description)
    Some text


  ENTRY(description){info}
    Multiline 

    text


  ENTRY(description)
    More text

#END
```

I am trying to get using preg_match_all a nice array that will provide me with all the individual entries and the fist line among everything else of course.

If I remove the first and last groups it provides the individual entries, but the thing is I need the first and last to ensure consistency plus the fist line provides some info I require.

I have been fiddling with this for some time now with no luck.
I have realized that what I am trying to achieve might require a bit of a different tactic, but I can't figure out what that is.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly in PHP/PCRE. It can be done in C# and Perl tho. In C# every group will capture all of its matches, and in Perl you can get the same effect.

In your case you'd have to do it in two passes/steps (if using regex, a parser can do it in a single pass). First match a proper `#LOG` to `#END` block, then extract all the entries from it.

Comment: Considering I might have 200-300 logs each with up to 10 entries. How wise would it be to run the main one to ding all logs and then loop to extract the entries into a nice array? Should I expect performance issues or better build the app in Perl? What about Python. Could it do it in one go?

Comment: 300 logs with 10 entries? Should be no performance issues at all, no matter what solution you choose. Pythons (standard) regex does not have all the features of PCRE (not to mention Perl).